# Adding new table with edit text in js

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make my web page dynamically when button clicked it should do add new edit texts

```js
function myCreateFunction() {
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
  cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr class="tr">
     <td><input type="text" class="Text1"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" class="Text2"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" class="Text3"/></td>
     <td><span class="lblStatus"></span></td>
     <td><button type="button" onclick="myCreateFunction()">Save projekt</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want.

In this line `var row = table.insertRow(-1);` I changed from `0` to `-1` for the new line to be inserted at the end

```js
function myCreateFunction() {
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  var row = table.insertRow(-1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="Text3"/>';
  cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="Text3"/>';
  cell3.innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="Text3"/>';
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr class="tr">
     <td><input type="text" class="Text1"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" class="Text2"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" class="Text3"/></td>
     <td><span class="lblStatus"></span></td>
     <td><button type="button" onclick="myCreateFunction()">Save projekt</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm glad to hear that I was able to help.